# NCurses appears to have a limited number of background colors (foreground colors work fine)

Tags: c++, ncurses

Ended up running into an unusual problem here: At program start, I'm looping through all supported 256 colors (just using defaults here) and creating a pair with every possible permutation-- this results in 65535 pairs of what I expected to be every fg/bg combination possible. I've verified these pairs are as expected by printing to stderr.

Just to check, my terminal supports 256 colors, 64k pairs, and color/pair reassignment.

Here's where the issue comes in: When attempting to print an arbitrary fg/bg color via attrset (and verifying that it is, in fact, the desired pair as printed above), foreground colors work fine, but the background color remains unchanged. If I hardcode all values to a single bg color it does as expected, and, likewise, making each permutation have identical fg/bg colors (ie, limiting the number of different fg/bg pairs to 256) also works as expected, and if I limit the pair generation code to only produce 256 different pairs, I see background colors as expected.

Fundamentally, this appears to be some sort of limit on how many unique pairs can be created (256); if I use all 64k color pairs with bg=0, I can address any given color by all its 256 pairs, and the resulting window is the same as the one where I set all fg/bg permutations (ie, it's as if ncurses internally used 0 for all bg colors.

Any ideas how I would approach this? I'm not seeing any memory issues in valgrind, and from what I can tell, the ncurses documentation implies my usage is supported.
Thanks!

Here's the code for generating pairs:

```
for(unsigned int c2 = 0; c2 < 256; c2++) {
        for(unsigned int c1 = 0; c1 < 256; c1++) {
            int pi = (c2)*256 + c1;
            init_extended_pair(pi, c1, c1);
            std::cerr << "init " << pi << " : " << c1 << ", " << c2 << "\n";
        }
    }
```

Calculating color IDs (I've verified this works independently- the +16 maps this to default ncurses color, since there are only 216 equally spaced colors)

```
unsigned int CursesObject::getColor(ColorRGBA col) {
    short r, g, b, er, eg, eb;
    r = int(col.r);
    g = int(col.g);
    b = int(col.b);
    
    er = r * 5 / 255;
    eg = g * 5 / 255;
    eb = b * 5 / 255;
    
    unsigned int colID = eb + eg*6 + er * 36;
    return colID + 16;
}
```

Calculating pair IDs for a given fg/bg, complete with debug code to retrieve the values of colors

```
void CursesObject::setColor(ColorRGBA fg, ColorRGBA bg) {
    if(fg == cfg && bg == cbg) return;
    else if(fg == bg) {
        attron(COLOR_PAIR(0));
        return;
    }
    //attrset(0x0);
    
    cfg = fg;
    cbg = bg;
    
    int pairID = this->getColor(fg) + (this->getColor(bg))*256;//\\\ + 16;
    //std::cout << "colorPair: " << pairID << " from cid = " << this->getColor(fg) << ", col = " << fg.toString() <<"\n";
    
    static int uidbgOff = 25;
    short dr, db, dg, bbr,bbb,bbg;
    int cp1, cp2;
    extended_pair_content(pairID, &cp1, &cp2);
    color_content(cp1, &dr, &dg, &db);
    color_content(cp2, &bbr, &bbg, &bbb);
    
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << pairID << " : " << dr << ", " << dg << ", " << db << " | " << bbr << ", " << bbg << ", " << bbb << " reported, pair " << cp1 << ":" << cp2 <<", should be " << this->getColor(fg) << ":" << this->getColor(bg)<<"\n";
    
    
    
    //sleep(5);
    attrset(COLOR_PAIR(pairID));
    this->write({10,uidbgOff}, ss.str());
    uidbgOff++;
    //this->update();
    
}
```

Interestingly enough, going by the output of the diagnostic functions, this code shouldn't be working *at all*, even only with fg colors. For instance, the output when trying to print red, orange, and teal is like so (it produces the correct colors, despite reporting them to be zero or completely wrong: red should be 1k,0,0 in RGB order - not 0,0,1k):

> 4804 : 0, 0, 1000 | 0, 0, 1000 reported, pair 196:18, should be 196:18
>
> 51664 : 0, 0, 0 | 0, 0, 0 reported, pair 0:0, should be 208:201
>
> 59168 : 0, 0, 0 | 0, 0, 0 reported, pair 0:0, should be 32:231

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example uses a mixture of calls that support *extended* color pairs and those which do not.  The `attron`, `attrset` calls store the color pair in an 8-bit field.  If you used `attr_on` and `attr_set`, those store the color pair in an integer (much larger than 8 bits).  The *extended_pair_content* builds on the latter, allowing use of color pairs larger than 32767.

Comment: That'll teach me to rely on online documentation, thank you! I've switched over to the extended functions (and it works just fine, mostly), but extended_pair_content() above 32767 still reads as 0,0. Any common gotchas I should check for?